# java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception cause null in Junit

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I'm trying to run my junit test case, but it showing as nullpointerexception. when I debug its showing as java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception cause null. Please help me.

public class StudentTest {

StudentService stuService;

```
StudentDAO stuDAO;
StudentVO stuVo;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("In Setup");
    stuVo=new StudentVO ();
    stuService=new StudentService();
   stuDAO=Mockito.mock(StudentDAO.class);
    //MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    stuVo.setStudId("123");
    stuVo.setName("user1");
   Mockito.when(stuDAO.getStudent(stuVo.getStuId())).thenReturn(student);

}

@Test
public void getStudent() throws DataAccessException {
    StudentVO stVO=stuService.getStudent(123)   ;
    Assert.assertEquals("123", stVO.getStuId());
}
```

}

My Service Class is

```
public class StudentService {
@Inject
StudentDAO stuDao;
public StudentVo getStudent(String id){
    return stuDao.getStudent(id);
}
public StudentDAO getStuDao() {
    return stuDao;
}
}
```

In failure trace its just showing as "java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at com.stu.StudentService.getStudent(StudentService.java:104)
at com.stu.junit.POCJunit.getgetStudent(StudentTest.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Can you include the full stacktrace please?

Comment: I have pasted all my code and error

Comment: I am facing same exception when I call KafkaTemplate.send().get(). Can anyone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by putting following code

```
@Mock
StudentDAO stuDAO;

@InjectMocks
StudentService stuService;
```

and in the setUp() method I have written

```
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code.

First on your mock for the DAO. You have no variable within the testing class called student. This should probably be stuVO unless you are converting from some other object into the stuVO object. Either way the variable student will need to be defined or replaced in that mock.

Another thing is that your inputs and outputs do not make sense. You have StudId as "123" in the setter but as an int in the assert. You may be doing a convert in the setter or getter but make sure your types match in the assert.

Another thing I just noticed.

You are not setting your mocked DAO inside of the service. This is causing your null pointer because your service is trying to call a method on a null DAO that I'm assuming is autowired in.

Try this

```
public class StudentTest {
    @ObjectUnderTest
    StudentService stuService;
    @Inject
    StudentDAO stuDAO;
    StudentVO stuVo;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In Setup");
        stuVo=new StudentVO ();   
        stuVo.setStudId("123");
        stuVo.setName("user1");
        Mockito.when(stuDAO.getStudent(stuVo.getStuId())).thenReturn(student);
    }

    @Test
    public void getStudent() throws DataAccessException {
        StudentVO stVO=stuService.getStudent(123)   ;
        Assert.assertEquals("123", stVO.getStuId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I have used @Inject in my servicer to inject the DAO.

Comment: Ok..Do you have @Inject on your DAO in the Test class? The code segment goes in between that part

Comment: My Service class

public class StudentService {
 @Inject
 StudentDAO stuDao;
 public StudentVo getStudent(int id){
  return stuDao.getStudent(id);
 }
 public StudentDAO getStuDao() {
  return stuDao;
 }
 
}

Comment: Hii In servicer if i put studentDao stuDao=new StudentDao then its working. But when ever i use @inject its not working.

Comment: try what I just added